# Growth in $n$ of average $\sum_i X_i/n$ for iid positive $X_i$ with unbounded expectation

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems, law-of-large-numbers

I am looking for references in the growth in $n$ of the empirical average
$\bar X = \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ where $X_i$ are iid non-negative random variables with unbounded expectation.

For instance, if $E[\sqrt{X_i}] = a$ is finite, we may apply the law of large numbers to $\frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{X_i}$ and a very loose bound that
$$\bar X \le \frac 1 n (\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{X_i} )^2 = n (a+o_P(1))^2.$$
Similarly if $E[X_i^p]=a$ for $p\in (0,1)$ then
$$\bar X \le \frac 1 n (\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^p)(n\bar X)^{1-p}$$
so $(\bar X)^p \le n^{1-p} (a+o_p(1))$ and $\bar X = O_p(n^{1/p - 1})$.

It is hopefully possible to obtain more precise results than these loose bounds. What are references on the subject or techniques that would yield better bounds?